# Adding data from datePicker to table view

Tags: ios, core-data, datepicker

I have two date pickers in my UIView and I am trying to figure out how to save their output using core data and displaying that data into a UITable view. Right now in my tableViewController I have:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Configure the cell...

    let CellID: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as UITableViewCell

    if let ip = indexPath as NSIndexPath! {
        var data: NSManagedObject = myLog[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject
        cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKeyPath("punchInTime") //error here (AnyObject is not identical to 'String')
    }

    return cell
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about resolving this error. I've been following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ymz6i07DRM just using date pickers instead of text fields, and learning as I go. But I'm missing something somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error.. If you know that the returnvalue of data.valueForKeyPath is always a string you could just write:

```
cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKeyPath("punchInTime") as String
```

In general.. You want to listen to UIControlEventValueChanged to get changes in the UIDatePickers. These you can write into CoreData. To get the data you refresh the table. To make retrieving the data easy look at NSFetchedResultsController.